# Chaining Optionals in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

Looking for a way to chain optionals so that the first one that is present is returned.  If none are present `Optional.empty()` should be returned.

Assuming I have several methods like this:

```
Optional<String> find1()
```

I'm trying to chain them:

```
Optional<String> result = find1().orElse( this::find2 ).orElse( this::find3 );
```

but of course that doesn't work because `orElse` expects a value and `orElseGet` expects a `Supplier`.

Comment: The version which expects a `Supplier` would be `.orElseGet()`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Use a Stream:

```
Stream.of(find1(), find2(), find3())
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .findFirst();
```

If you need to evaluate the find methods lazily, use supplier functions:

```
Stream.of(this::find1, this::find2, this::find3)
    .map(Supplier::get)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .findFirst();
```

Comment: findFirst() actually returns an empty optional if no items are found, so I'll remove the orElse().

Comment: Yours is even better than mine - except for readability: amybe the first `map` could be changed to `.map(Supplier::get)` and the second one to `.map(Optional::get)`. When you are on it, `.filter(Optional::isPresent)` would be fine as well, but that doesn't hurt readability as much as the others.

Comment: That works though its kind of a lot of code for a simple problem. Makes me think it should have been built in in the Optional api

Comment: One thing that is surely missing from Optional is a converter into Stream, not just for this use case. Then this would be a bit more manageable: `Stream.of(opt1,opt2,opt3).flatMap(Optional::stream).findFirst()`.

Comment: To be consistent the second version can be written as `Stream.of(this::find1, this::find2, this::find3)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik maybe you are aware of this already, but `Optional.stream()` is going to be added to [JDK9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050820)

Comment: To chain optionals from methods that take parameters... -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818506/java-8-optional-orelse-optional#answer-28833677

Comment: Wouldn't the application of `Supplier::get` cause an exception if one of the `find` Optionals is empty? It seems to me we still need to filter with `Optional::isPresent` first.

Or am I missing something? Maybe I'm confused here.

Answer (score 63):

Inspired by Sauli's answer, it is possible to use the `flatMap()` method.

```
Stream.of(this::find1, this::find2, this::find3)
  .map(Supplier::get)
  .flatMap(o -> o.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
  .findFirst();
```

Converting an Optional into a Stream is cumbersome. Apparently, this is going to be [fixed with JDK9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050820). So this could be written as

```
Stream.of(this::find1, this::find2, this::find3)
  .map(Supplier::get)
  .flatMap(Optional::stream)
  .findFirst();
```

**Update after Java 9 was released**

Although the original question was about Java 8, [`Optional::or`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-) was introduced in Java 9. With it, the problem could be solved as follows

```
Optional<String> result = find1()
  .or(this::find2)
  .or(this::find3);
```

Answer (score 52):

You could do it like this:

```
Optional<String> resultOpt = Optional.of(find1()
                                .orElseGet(() -> find2()
                                .orElseGet(() -> find3()
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new WhatEverException()))));
```

Though I'm not sure it improves readability IMO. Guava provides a way to chain Optionals:

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

Optional<String> resultOpt = s.find1().or(s.find2()).or(s.find3());
```

It could be another alternative for your problem but does not use the standard Optional class in the JDK.

If you want to keep the standard API, you could write a simple utility method:

```
static <T> Optional<T> or(Optional<T> first, Optional<T> second) {
    return first.isPresent() ? first : second;
}
```

and then:

```
Optional<String> resultOpt = or(s.find1(), or(s.find2(), s.find3()));
```

If you have a lot of optionals to chains, maybe it's better to use the Stream approach as other mentionned already.

Comment: The solution with the utility method is probably as readable as it can get. Too bad java's Optional does not have the same method as the Guava one

Comment: `or(Optional<T>... opts)` would be an improvement. Varargs with generics, though, are an unfortunate mix.

Comment: Your first approach could throw an exception even if `find1` or `find2` would return a value.

Comment: Whenever `find3` returns an empty `Optional`.

Comment: @zeroflagL Yes it will throw a new WhatEverException in this case (the OP didn't originally precise that he would have an empty optional in this case). Not sure if you can do it in one line, though I don't recommend to use this approach.

Comment: You could always do : `Optional<String> resultOpt = Optional.ofNullable(s.find1().orElse(s.find2().orElse(s.find3().orElse(null))));` but that would assume that a null value is equivalent to an empty Optional, so it depends on what the op wants.

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding. If `find1` returns a value (= non-empty `Optional`) then the return value of `find3` simply doesn't matter. But in your first solution an exception can be thrown despite the fact we already have a valid result. In other words: Ideally `find3` shouldn't have been called in the first place.

Comment: @zeroflagL Ah yes thanks for pointing this out! You can also use `orElseGet` to have a lazy evaluation. I've updated my answer accordingly. (There's still the use case with 3 empty optional though I don't think it's possible to do it in one line).

Answer (score 17):

## Since Java 9

*most likely case the readers are looking for (today)*

```
result = find1()
    .or(this::find2)
    .or(this::find3);
```

## Java 8

```
result = Optional.ofNullable(find1()
    .orElse(find2()
      .orElse(find3()
        .orElse(null))));
```

PERFORMANCE: the above **Java 8** solution pre-calls **find2()** and **find3()** each time, even when (later) **find1()** evaluation returns non-empty.

UPDATE: Performance optimal **Java 8** solution with lazy evaluation (thanks to @Alexander's comment) would be:

```
result = Optional.ofNullable(find1()
    .orElseGet(() -> find2()
      .orElseGet(() -> find3()
        .orElse(null))));      // <-- null would be the last resort, when all findN are empty.
                               //     #ofNullable (in the 1st line would wrap it to Optional
                               //     and return Optional.empty() as OP requires.
```

Comment: @FabienWarniez it's been answered in 2017 already https://stackoverflow.com/a/34398891/2223027

Comment: For java 8 it is wrong proposal. All Optional get evaluated, even if the first has a not-nullable value. Usually null values - marker of the illegal state and you should throw an expeption. Check how this work, for instance:
`String value = Optional.ofNullable("str").orElse(Optional.<String>ofNullable(null).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException()));`
And the right solution with lazy evaluation:
```String value = Optional.ofNullable("str").orElseGet(() -> Optional.<String>ofNullable(null).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException()));```

Comment: @FabienWarniez, no, the proposal for Java 8  is pretty bad. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Java 9+
find1().or(() -> find2()).or(() -> find3());


// Java 8
Optional.ofNullable(
   find1().orElse(
      find2().orElse(
         find3().orElse( null )
)));
```

Comment: I wish they just had `.orElseOf(1,2,3)` or something like that

Answer (score 3):

Based on Alexis C's answer, but without the nesting of `orElse`s

```
String result = find1()
                   .map(Optional::of)
                   .orElseGet(Foo::find2())
                   .map(Optional::of)
                   .orElseGet(Foo::find3())
                   .orElseThrow(() -> new WhatEverException())
```

Remove the `orElseThrow` if you want an `Optional<String>` as the result instead.

The trick is to wrap each optional returned by the `findX` to another optional before each `orElseGet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 9's `or`.

If the functions that provides the data you need return it plain, you can do it like that:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(supplier1())
  .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(supplier2()))
  .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(supplier3()))
  .orElse(fallbackValue)
```

I often statically import `ofNullable` to ease readability. You can also play with `orElse` or `orElseGet` to close the chain if needed.

Now, if the functions that provides the data you need return it wrapped by a `Optional` already and you cannot or do not want to change the return type, you could do this trick to start the chain:

```java
Optional.empty()
  .or(supplier1)
  .or(supplier2)
  .orElse(fallbackValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

*for cascading chaining You could use* `ifPresentOrElse`

```
find1().ifPresentOrElse( System.out::println, new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    find2().ifPresentOrElse( System.out::println, new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        find3().ifPresentOrElse( System.out::println, new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            System.err.println( "nothing found…" );
          }
        } );
      }
    } );
  }
} );
```

to do something with the value of the `Optional` You had to replace the `System.out::println` with Your `Consumer`
*(different Consumers would also be possible in this solution)*

Answer (score 0):

My common generic solution for all those issues:

```
public static <T> T firstMatch(final Predicate<T> matcher, final T orElse, final T... values) {
  for (T t : values) {
    if (matcher.test(t)) {
      return t;
    }
  }
  return orElse;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> firstPresent(final Optional<T>... values) {
  return firstMatch(Optional::isPresent, Optional.empty(), values);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To perform **Optional Chaining** First *convert* **Stream to Optional** Using either of the two methods

1. findAny() or findFirst()
2. min() / max()

Once optional is obtained optional has two more instance method which are also present in Stream class i.e filter and map().
use these on methods and to check output use ifPresent(System.out :: Println)

ex:

**Stream s = Stream.of(1,2,3,4);**

**s.findFirst().filter((a)->a+1).ifPresent(System.out :: Println)**

Output is : 2

Comment: First: The filter method must return a boolean. "incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression int cannot be converted to boolean"

Comment: You get a NPE when the input is null.
`Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(null,2,3,4);
s.findFirst().map((a)->a+1).ifPresent(System.out::println);`

Answer (score -3):

Maybe one of

```
    public <T> Optional<? extends T> firstOf(Optional<? extends T> first, @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Supplier<Optional<? extends T>>... supp) {
        if (first.isPresent()) return first;
        for (Supplier<Optional <? extends T>> sup : supp) {
            Optional<? extends T> opt = sup.get();
            if (opt.isPresent()) {
                return opt;
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public <T> Optional<? extends T> firstOf(Optional<? extends T> first, Stream<Supplier<Optional<? extends T>>> supp) {
        if (first.isPresent()) return first;
        Stream<Optional<? extends T>> present = supp.map(Supplier::get).filter(Optional::isPresent);
        return present.findFirst().orElseGet(Optional::empty);
    }
```

will do.

The first one iterates over an array of suppliers. The first non-empty `Optional<>` is returned. If we don't find one, we return an empty `Optional`.

The second one does the same with a `Stream` of `Suppliers` which is traversed, each one asked (lazily) for their value, which is then filtered for empty `Optional`s. The first non-empty one is returned, or if no such exists, an empty one.

Comment: Wow, again a -1 w/o notice what could be improved.

Comment: Because the answers above do exactly the same in much more clear and elegant way.