# Java stream ifPresent orElse /orElseGet

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Hello What am I doing wrong here

I want to get the foundation Id , if its not present then get Insurance Type.. the code snippets are pasted below ..  but I get an error at the orElse part I even tried orElseGet() ...It says "target type of Lambda must be an interface"..

```
String type = getFoundationId(companyInsurances).orElse(()->getInsuranceType(insurance, companyInsurances));
```

…

```
private Optional<String> getInsuranceType(Insurance insurance, List<CompanyInsurance> companyInsurances) {
    return InsurancePeriodHelper.findFirstCompanyInsuranceOfType(companyInsurances, CompanyInsuranceType.POLICY_HOLDER.getValue())
             .map(companyInsurance-> insurance.getProduct());
}

private Optional<String> getFoundationId(List<CompanyInsurance> companyInsurances) {
    return InsurancePeriodHelper.findFirstCompanyInsuranceOfType(companyInsurances, CompanyInsuranceType.FOUNDATION.getValue())
            .map(companyInsurance -> companyInsurance.getCompany().getFoundationIdentifier().toString());
}
```

Comment: `.orElse(getInsuranceType(insurance, companyInsurances));`

Comment: I tried that as well and I get  ..  orElse
(java.lang.String)
in Optional cannot be applied
to
(java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>)

Comment: yeah. right! `getFoundationId(...).orElse(getInsuranceType(...).orElse(""));` it's better follow @Ravinda's answer

Comment: Might just be a duplicate of(quite related) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514704/chaining-optionals-in-java-8

Answer (score 0):

With Java-9 and above you could simply chain such `Optional`s using [`Optional.or`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) as:

```
String type = getFoundationId(companyInsurances)
        .or(() -> getInsuranceType(insurance, companyInsurances))
        .orElse("defaultValue");
```