# Calling contains on a list for an optional value in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

In Java 8,

I currently have a lambda that looks like this:

```
.createSomething((acceptableStates, someProxy) -> (userId) ->   
    acceptableStates.contains(someProxy.getSomeAttributeId(userId)))
```

However, we have changed someProxy.getSomeAttributeId to return an `Optional<String>` instead of a string.

What's the cleanest / most accepted way to essentially check for if `acceptableStates` contains the value of `someProxy.getSomeAttributeId(userId)` if the attribute returned isn't empty?

(Note: `acceptableStates` is still a list of strings, not of `Optional<String>`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
.... userId -> someProxy.getSomeAttributeId(userId)
                        .map(acceptableStates::contains)
                        .orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: This may be obvious, but what is the reason for using Boolean.FALSE over just "false"?

Comment: @Mei probably no reason for your case... just wanted to make that obvious, could be easily replace with plain `false`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I see no very clean solution here. Refer to this question: [Functional style of Java 8's Optional.ifPresent and if-not-Present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773024/functional-style-of-java-8s-optional-ifpresent-and-if-not-present)

Additionally, you even have to save the optional in a variable if the call to `getSomeAttributeId` does cost resources.

```
.createSomething((acceptableIds, someProxy) -> (userId) ->
    {
       Optional<String> attrId = someProxy.getSomeAttributeId(userId);
       return attrId.isPresent() ? acceptableStates.contains(attrId.get()) : false;
    })
```

Comment: `condition1? condition2: false` means `condition1 && condition2`, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335722/calling-contains-on-a-list-for-an-optional-value-in-java/45336092#comment77665018_45336011)…

Comment: Good catch, I agree. But I wouldn't say that necessarily adds to readability. I would keep `?` since the intention is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend writing understandable and clear code like this snippet:

```
Optional<SomeAttributeId> optional = someProxy.getSomeAttributeId(userId);

return optional.isPresent() && acceptableStates.contains(optional.get‌​());
```

If there should not be thrown an exception (1) when `someProxy.getSomeAttributeId(userId)` is an empty optional:

```
acceptableStates.contains(someProxy.getSomeAttributeId(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception()))
```

Or unless you have the default value (2) to fill up the result with:

```
acceptableStates.contains(someProxy.getSomeAttributeId(userId).orElse(DEFAUT_VALUE))
```

---

My point:

Do not pursue Java 8 features which will mess everything up, especially in cases where a simple boolean expression could be used. I had experience refactoring some code toward plain Java statements because new people (1.1) came in a project could not get what the code does. With the time, even I (as a writer) barely can do so (1.2).

Also, with that *"lambda chain"* style, one slight change could cause rewriting a snippet/method entirely (2).

It is always fun to poke around n-nested lambdas, where n > 2 (3).

---

Anyway, if you don't share my point, [@Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059372/eugene) proposed a good way to go with.

Comment: Every time you see a boolean literal in a compound expression, you can be sure that there is an (usually simpler) alternative without, `optional.isPresent()? acceptableStates.contains(optional.get()): false;` can be replaced by `optional.isPresent()&&acceptableStates.contains(optional.get())`

Answer (score 0):

```java
return value.isPresent() && value.get().contains("some-text");
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you tried explaining your answer in addition to posting a code snippet next time :)