# java 8: Using Optional with lambda

Tags: if-statement, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

**How can I code the logic below using Optional and lambda?**
I have two Lists

> List success = new ArrayList<>();
>   
>  
>   List failures = new ArrayList<>();

And there is an object

> RoomTypes value

for which `value.getErrorType()` could be NULL or not and `value.getId()` returns integer.

I would like to update `success` and `failure` with `value.getId()` list according to `value.getErrorType()` being null.

Something like:

```
if(value.getErrorType().equals(NULL)){
   success.add(value.getId())
}
else{
   failure.add(value.getId())
}
```

Comment: Do you have list of values or just one value? Why would you want to use optional here? Check the source where Null is coming and if you can change that then you can think of the same. Look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773024/functional-style-of-java-8s-optional-ifpresent-and-if-not-present

Comment: `value.getId()` returns single value.

Comment: What's wrong with value.getErrorType() == null ? success.add(..) : failure.add(..);

Comment: I would like to modify above code using `Optional`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functional style of Java 8's Optional.ifPresent and if-not-Present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773024/functional-style-of-java-8s-optional-ifpresent-and-if-not-present)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming, `NULL` actually means `null`, you can use

```
Optional.ofNullable(value.getErrorType())
        .map(x -> failure).orElse(success).add(value.getId());
```

though it is not recommend to use `Optional` for such a case, as a similar ordinary check is straight-forward:

```
(value.getErrorType() == null? success: failure).add(value.getId());
```

Comment: More condensed and elegant solution than mine !