# Java Optional filter xml tags with certain conditions

Tags: java, option-type

I am trying to parse xml and filter nodes which do not meet the certain criteria (do not have an id attribute or this attribute is empty)

My xml looks like rather simple:

```
<node/>            <!-- not ok node-->
<node id = ""/>    <!-- not ok node-->
<node id="">       <!-- not ok node-->
    <type>4</type>
</node>

<node id = "1"/>   <!-- OK node-->
```

So there are 3 wrong nodes which have an empty id tag or do not have it at all, and 1 OK node with correct id tag. Parsing and filtering code is as follows (Java's `Optional` is used, the code does not work and produces errors):

```
try (StaxStreamProcessor processor = new 
     StaxStreamProcessor(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(graphConfigPath)))){

  Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<>();
  XMLStreamReader reader = processor.getReader();
  Loggers.debug("started parsing");
  while (reader.hasNext()) {
     switch (reader.getLocalName()) {
        case NODE_TAG:
            Optional.ofNullable(reader.getAttributeValue(null, ID_ATTR))
                    .filter(nodeId -> nodes.add(parseNode(reader))) // error here: Unhandled exception: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
                    .orElse(Loggers.debug("Node with empty id attribute")); //error here: orElse (java.lang.String) in Optional cannot be applied to (Void)
      }
   }
}
```

So if the Node is wrong, it should not be put into `nodes` collection, but log message should be written. If the node is OK, it goes into collection without log messages. Any idea how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

**UPD_1**
Found a solution how to collect correct nodes (which have id present and not empty):

```
Optional.ofNullable(parseNode(reader))
        .filter(node -> node.getId() != null && node.getId() != "" )  
        .ifPresent(nodes::add);
```

but how to get the other ones (wrong nodes and write a log about them)? It says it is not possible to write anything after `ifPresent()`

Thank you.

**UPD_2**

finally managed to solve the issue with `spring-data` (thx to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773024/functional-style-of-java-8s-optional-ifpresent-and-if-not-present/56131331#56131331)) post.

```
Optional opt = Optional.ofNullable(parseNode(reader))
                       .filter(node -> node.getId() != null && node.getId() != "" );

//Runnable notFoundAction = () -> Loggers.warning("Node with empty id attribute");

 Optionals.ifPresentOrElse(
                            opt,
                            nodes::add,
                            () -> Loggers.warning("Node with empty id attribute")
                        );
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: _the code does not work and produces errors_ In order to help you fix the error, it would help if you posted the error message and stack trace you are getting.

Comment: its IDE errors, it does not allow to run the code. Btw, I added error messages next to code lines, in comments

Comment: Is it mandatory to use StAX? Can you use other parsers like Jsoup?

Comment: yes, its a legacy code. Actually the problem is in Optional, cannot make it work

Comment: Legacy code means you have to use _StAX_, right? Do you also have to use `Optional`?

Comment: yes, both of these are required

Comment: Please post code for class `Node` - the type of each element in `Set<Node> nodes`

Comment: Please post code for method `parseNode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since JDK 9, class `Optional` has method [ifPresentOrElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-)

```java
Runnable notFoundAction = () -> Loggers.debug("Node with empty id attribute");
Optional.ofNullable(parseNode(reader))
        .filter(node -> node.getId() != null && node.getId() != "" )  
        .ifPresentOrElse(nodes::add, notFoundAction);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. Unfortunately I am not on Java 9 yet, is it possible to do the same with `Spring Optionals` (Optionals.ifPresentOrElse()) in Java 8? Thank you.