# How to use Java Optional without if condition to add different logic

Tags: java, option-type

I want to apply different logic to Optional value like below

```
Optional<String> alarm = getAlarm();
if (alarm.isPresent()) {
    testAutoStopAndRollback(alarm.get());
} else {
    testWithoutAutoStopAndRollback();
}
```

Is there a more concise way to implement the same logic?
I know I can move half of the logic to `ifPresent()`

```
alarm.ifPresent(name -> testAutoStopAndRollback(name));
```

How can I do the rest part?

To clarify the question, my code is stick to Java 8 so I won't be able to use [ifPresentOrElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) in Java 9.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like your first example is fine already.
Unless you can upgrade to Java 9, [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) does not contain a method like ifPresentOrElse. 
Just stick to the first rule of programming: "If it works, don't touch it!" :)

If you want to create more classes to clean up your code a little, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773024/functional-style-of-java-8s-optional-ifpresent-and-if-not-present).

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do it by returning some value from `testAutoStopAndRollback` and `testWithoutAutoStopAndRollback`, for example i would return boolean values to identify value is present or not

```
testAutoStopAndRollback(val) ---> returns true
testWithoutAutoStopAndRollback ---> returns false
```

And then using `Optional`

```
boolean value = alarm.map(this::testAutoStopAndRollback).orElseGet(this::testWithoutAutoStopAndRollback);
```

Comment: Changing the signature of the method to be invoked to start returning a value while it was void, doesn't make much sense imho.