# View Single Record in Spring Boot and Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, api, crud

I'm trying to develop a simple crud application using Spring and Mongodb.

When I'm trying to develop view single data function, I get no error.

But it return value as null when I try in Postman.

Could you please help me to find what is the wrong with my code?

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/patient/{id}")
    public Optional<Patients> findTicketById(@PathVariable("id") @NotNull String id){
        System.out.println(id);
        return patientRepository.findById(id);
    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends MongoRepository<Patients, Long> {
    Optional<Patients> findById(String id);
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends MongoRepository<Patients, String> {
    Optional<Patients> findById(String id);
}

Though I changed Repository by removing Long and adding String it also gives the same thing.

Comment: You get `Optional` . So you need to first user `isPresent()` in if condition. Then you can use `get()` to get the object. And the post is not clear. You need to post the model class too.. Do yo have any parent mapping? (Is the id printing inside the method in System.out.println).. What is the query printing in the console?

Comment: Have a look on Optional https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional

Comment: Can you show the sample data inserted in your collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifPresentOrElse` , check for the usages :

[Functional style of Java 8's Optional.ifPresent and if-not-Present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773024/functional-style-of-java-8s-optional-ifpresent-and-if-not-present)